# Multi Axes Voting using Fiverstar, Views, Reference

Tags: 7, rating

I have tried several different tutorials on how to accomplish this. Most were for drupal 6, but there were few for drupal 7 but none seem to make sense to the modules being used currently that are in dev or stable. The Node Review module seems to be the closest thing to what I need but that requires some hacking to make it work for my particular use. I have several other modules that I've experimented with. Rate 7.x-1.3 Seemed to have potential.

How would I be able to make a system like the following use these modules?;

- Node Reference   7.x-2.0+8-dev
- Fivestar 7.x-2.0-alpha1+22-dev
- Views    7.x-3.3

What I am looking for a content-type: Business. These will have several businesses that people can rate based on different criteria. Multi Axes Rating on separate page or tab. The Review can be a separate content type. Not required thou.

Comment: Hi, maybe I can't understand this concept of Multi Axes Voting. Why don't you just add several Fivestar (or Rates) to your content-type, one for each criteria?

Comment: The problem is that the users of the site will be creating reviews of businesses. So if I create the business with multiple axes built in.. Only the person that creates the business node will be able to input anything, and it would only get to be done once. What I need is 1 [business] to MANY [reviews] (one review per business per user)

Comment: @Digital Fire - did you find a solution on how to calculate the rating in a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many vote fields (using Rate or Fivestar) as you want to your Reviews, one vote for each criteria you want to make available.
Your Reviews can be a new Content-Type (then you would use a Relationship in the Business View) or you can use Comments (of Business) for this propose. Both Content-Type and Comments are customizable: you can add fields to them.

My first choice would be to add *n* Fivestar rating fields to Business's Comments. You can do that in Business Content-Type Edition, in the "Comment Fields" tab.

But if you want each user to make only one review and have more control/customizations, then a new Content-Type for Reviews can make your life easier.

Comment: This works, now am just trying to to get my views to calculate the average of votes through the reference..